# How to easily move Visual Studio to a different computer w/ different drive names?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2012

I have a Visual Studio 2012 development environment on my PC.

I want to move it to a new laptop for travel.

The old project files are on an E: partition.

I don't want to create an E: partition on the laptop because I believe that really screwed up windows 8.1 on the laptop recently (I did this once before) and I had to reinstall Windows on a new drive Dell supplied (don't ask; Ugh!)

Does Visual studio have a way to migrate a project and change the drive letter of the paths in a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you screwed up something majorly, all VS project paths are stored as relative ones. Simply copy the folder over and it'll work.

Comment: The imported project solution file cannot load. It is throwing errors looking for paths on an E: drive base.

Comment: Hence the "unless". It's ok though, the `.csproj` file is a normal XML, simply open it in a text editor (or right click it in VS and unload it then edit it for syntax completion) and change the paths yourself -- preferably to normal, relative paths.

Comment: So you are saying I screwed up something majorly? This is an ASP.Net project. Projects are stored in .sln files. What would you say I screwed up in the project, Blindy?

Comment: Creating (or adding) the files in your project. Because let's be honest, if you were to work with others and forced everyone to have the same exact folder structure -- well, I'd honestly fire you. Also, while projects are stored in solutions (.sln files), the source files themselves are stored in projects (.csproj). It's the later you need to edit to fix this (unless even your project is using an absolute path, but that shouldn't be the case).

Answer (score 0):

In further research I found a workaround.

The .sln file in an ASP.NET project contains, among other things, the **top level** path to the project.

The .sln file is text editable. If you edit the top level path to the project, the project will then load.

As far as the original question : "does Microsoft offer an automated way to migrate projects", I have not yet  found an answer to that.